# Shell: Prompt user to enter a directory path

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm looking for a Bash equivalent of Python's os.path.join. I'm trying to prompt the user for a directory path, which then will be used (with the help of path join equivalent) to do other stuff.

Comment: You can always just use `${dirpath}/${filename}`. Python has `os.path.join` because `/` isn't portable, it only works on Unix-like pathnames. But `bash` only works with Unix-based pathnames. (Even if you build a MinGW/native `bash` for Windows.)

Comment: I want to do it through a shell script. cd path didn't work for me. @abarnert I tried echo to get the path, but that again I'm totally skeptical about.

Comment: I don't understand the question(s) in that last comment. If your shell script has variables named `dirpath` and `filename`, then `${dirpath}/${filename}` joins them together, just like `os.path.join(dirpath, filename)` would in Python.

Comment: `"$dirpath/$filename"` is perfectly valid.  Don't forget to double-quote the string in case there are embedded spaces.  You don't need `{ }` around the variables because `/` terminates the variable name.

Comment: @cdarke: I don't like to leave the braces off in code for novices who don't know the rules for identifiers and don't seem likely to ask until they have a bug 3 months from now…

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly safe to use, e.g., `"${dirpath}/${filename}"` in a `bash` script.

`bash` only understands POSIX-style pathnames. Even if you build a MinGW/native `bash` on Windows. That means `/` is always the path separator. And it means that it never hurts to put two slashes in a row, so even if `$dirpath` happens to end in '/', everything is fine.

So, for example:

```
$ cat join.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -n 'Path: '
read dirpath
echo -n 'Filename: '
read filename
ls -l "${dirpath}/${filename}"
$ ./join.sh
Path: /etc/
Filename: hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  236 Sep 15  2014 /etc/hosts
```

---

In Python, it's not safe to just use `/` this way. Python handles native-format pathnames on POSIX and POSIX-like systems, but also handles native-format pathnames on Windows.*, in which the path separator is `\`, two backslashes have a special meaning in certain places, you have drive letters to worry about, etc. So, you have to use `os.path.join` to be portable.

<sub>* It also has code for classic Mac (which uses colons), VMS (which uses a mix of different things that you don't want to know about), etc., if you're using an old enough Python.</sub>

Comment: @cdarke: Yes, Windows NT does accept `/` paths. Except that they're not guaranteed to work in a `\\.\` "long Unicode" path, may not be sent properly over CIFS networks in an SMB path, may be confused with flags by some command-line tools (including the ones that come with Windows itself), etc.

Comment: @cdarke: What about it in particular? That's a long article. (Also, why link to a link to the article instead of to the article itself?)

Comment: For specific uses of the result it is save to join two path parts using a slash.  It is not save e. g. if you string-compare this result with a given path, e. g. `if [ "${part1}/${part2}" = "$(pwd)" ]`.  The Python `os.path.join()` is superior in this aspect; it removes additional slashes.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the `readlink` command. You can use `readlink -m "some/path"` to convert a path to the canonical path format. It's not quite path.join but it does provide similar functionality.

Edit: As someone pointed out to me `readlink` is actually more like `os.path.realpath`. It is also a GNU extension and not available on all *nix systems. I will leave my answer here in case it still helps in some way.

Comment: That's not similar to `os.path.join`. It _is_ similar to `os.path.realpath`, but that's a completely different thing from `os.path.join`. Also, `readlink -m` is a GNU extension that isn't on other *nix systems. (The OP did tag this "linux", but also "unix"; I'm not sure if that means he wants a portable solution or not…)

Comment: ⁺¹ for mentioning the (ab)use of `readlink -m` to canonize a path.  Didn't know that one yet :)